# LARAVEL get errors from isValid in file upload

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, file-upload, upload

I'm using Laravel,
so far all file uploads went great so I never had to use it,
but now one is failing.

How do I learn what the error from a file upload is in this code?

```
if(!request()->file($fileName)->isValid()){
    //some action to learn of the error
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`request()->file($fileName)` will return an instance of `\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`. Along with `isValid()`, you can call `getError()` to get the identifying integer of the upload error, and `getErrorMessage()` to get the human error string.

```
$file = request()->file($fileName);

if (!$file->isValid()) {
    $error = $file->getErrorMessage();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Great, this helped. Thanks!